# Globally configuring Javascript for notebooks on Jupyterhub

Tags: javascript, ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I would like to replace each user's  `custom.js` file with a global version. The only way I can figure out how to do this currently is to overwrite `~/.ipython/profile_default/static/custom/custom.js` after a user runs their first ipython notebook and their **.ipython** directory gets instantiated.

There must be a better way, either by providing some global version of `custom.js` or by replacing the default `custom.js` file during installation. In theory, one could also create symbolic links to a global `custom.js` but this didn't work for me for some reason.

I see that there is a file `/srv/notebook/notebook/static/custom/custom.js` on my system - but modifying it doesn't alter the `custom.js` that gets installed for each user.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You shouldn't have to wait for the directory to be created - creating the directory yourself and writing `custom.js` should work. `custom.js` is intended for user overrides, so if it exists in the users directory, your systemwide copy will not be loaded.

Comment: Thanks @ThomasK, that is definitely a good idea, though I'm worried that by taking this approach I could end up putting a wrong or outdated copy of other configuration files inside of .ipython.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm running jupyterhub with dockerspawner, and have just found a solution [here](https://github.com/bgruening/docker-jupyter-notebook/blob/master/Dockerfile).

To make the `custom.js` file adopted by each user, you can derivate the jupyter/base-notebook image by adding it to each user's custom directory:

```
ADD ./custom.js /home/$NB_USER/.jupyter/custom/custom.js
```

Note this path is the path defined in the [jupyter notebook doc](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Notebook/JavaScript%20Notebook%20Extensions.html#custom.js).

Hope this helps anyone having the same problem.